# Deploy previous git commit to AWS

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, deployment

I want to test how a previous version of a project deploys to my Elastic Beanstalk environment. I've used `git checkout xxxxx` to revert to my previous version, but when I used `eb deploy` I get the following response:

> WARNING: Git is in a detached head state. Using branch "default".
>   WARNING: Git is in a detached head state. Using branch "default".
>   WARNING: Git is in a detached head state. Using branch "default".
>   ERROR: This branch does not have a default environment. You must
>   either specify an environment by typing "deploy my-env-name" or set a
>   default environment by typing "eb use my-env-name".

I ran `eb deploy [my-eb-environment-name]` and it appeared to work:

> WARNING: Git is in a detached head state. Using branch "default".
>   Creating application version archive "app-9d67-180108_150155".
>   Uploading: [##################################################] 100% 
>   Done...

But the deployment still failed.

Did it deploy the checked out version, as I wanted it to, or is it still pushing the version I suspect is broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annoyingly it seems checking out a previous commit doesn't remove files from the directory of the most recent commit. So that means files that didn't exist in the prior commit will still be there, and so uploaded via `eb deploy`.

Comment: Yes, old files persists. It is annoying. It is supposed to be clean deployment. There should be a way to clean deploy.